# How to implement SSO with: Roundcube Zimbra + CAS?

Tags: cas, zimbra, roundcube

We're developing a mail system whose mail client is **Roundcube** using with **Zimbra** as mail server.
My task is integrating them with a **CAS** server which enable them to *Single Sign On*. After days of researching I confuse that's impossible.

So how can I implement SSO the mail application with CAS?

Comment: Just to understand, why do you want to use roundcube on top of Zimbra since comes with his own very powerfull (in my opinion) webmail client?

Comment: Yep, but we need to customize the mail client since it's limited by zimbra

Comment: Well it's up to you but you wan build zimlet and skins in Zimbra.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this? It might still apply:
https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/CASifying_Zimbra_6.0

and this:
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/CASifying+Zimbra

If Roundcube  is a fat client for the server, not sure if it can leverage SSO. You need to experiment.

Comment: I had CASified my Zimbra but it just work for Zimbra mail client, not Roundcube mail client

Comment: Right. That's a shortcoming of the mail client. It does not realize Zimbra is using CAS for SSO.